# cufon refresh in ajax

Tags: javascript

im trying to refresh cufon after load more button clicked.
load more button uses ajax to fetch more content and by that , cufon can not initialized.
i used document.onmouseover to refresh cufon but to do that user needs to mouseover on new loaded content.
what i am trying to tell is how can i do this cufon.refresh thing without mouseovering?
like document.ready , document.load ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

document.onmouseover = function()
{
Cufon.refresh();
}
            ipb.forums.fetchMore = {
                                            'f': parseInt("{$this->request['showforum']}")  ,
                    'st': parseInt("{$this->request['st']}"),
                    'sort_by': "{$this->request['sort_by']}",
                    'sort_key': "{$this->request['sort_key']}",
                    'topicfilter': "{$this->request['topicfilter']}",
                    'prune_day': "{$this->request['prune_day']}",
                    'max_topics': "{$this->settings['display_max_topics']}"
                };

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want for Cufon to refresh when the `fetchMore` AJAX request has completed?

Comment: exactly precisely indeed.

Comment: Have you investigated the `DOMSubtreeModified` event?

Comment: yes but couldnt make it work.

Comment: Off topic: Why use cufon? use webfonts - it's faster and altogether the way how it should be done.

Comment: cufon is much more diffrent from the others , its embedding the font so it looks like pretty much an image made in photoshop , otherwise they are just texts.